Unable to insert new contact from instant app in Android 14
How to save/insert a new contact from instant app?
Tried inserting a new contact using intent by following developer docs like so:
val intent = Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION).apply {
    type = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE
}
intent.apply {
    putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, contactEmail)
    putExtra(
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL_TYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK
    )
    putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, contactNumber)
    putExtra(
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK
    )
    putExtra(
        ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, contactName
    )
}
startActivity(intent)

This didn't work, but adding createChooser seems to work upto Android 13, but doesn't work in Android 14
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""))

Is there any alternative or should I try raising an issue in issuetracker.google.com? (componentid:316045)
